# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ids') , while using globalSelectors,simpleSelectors of redux toolkit in createEntityAdapter

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern, redux-toolkit

I am Learning Redux Toolkit and using createEntityAdapter for a simple todo app.
the problem is that I am getting errors whenever I try to access the todos from globalselectors or/and simple selectors of the todoAdapter.

I've created a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-createentityadapter-forked-6jfvk) for this

This is the todoReducer code where I am setting

```
const todosAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (todo) => todo._id,
});

const initialState = {
  fetching: true,
  error: null,
  addingNew: false,
};

const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: todosAdapter.getInitialState(initialState),
  reducers: {
    pushNewTodo: todosAdapter.addOne,
    addManyTodos: todosAdapter.addMany,
    removeTodo: todosAdapter.removeOne,
    editTodo: todosAdapter.updateOne,
  },
  extraReducers: { ... }
})

//* Errror in this line , 
export const globalTodosReducers = todosAdapter.getSelectors((st) => st.todos);
export const simpleTodosReducers = todosAdapter.getSelectors();

export const {
  addTodo,
  removeTodo,
  toggleTodo,
  editTodo,
  clearTodos
} = todosSlice.actions;
export default todosSlice.reducer;
```

And when I want to use simpleSelectors , I get error in that also

```
// TodoApp.js
function TodoApp() {
  .
  .
  .
  // * Error in these lines
  // const todos = globalTodosReducers.selectAll();
  const todos = simpleTodosReducers.selectAll();


.
.
.
```

error is

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ids')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by `getSelectors` contains many selector functions. Each one requires you to pass in the state object that contains the data you want to select from. You had the right idea here:

```
todosAdapter.getSelectors((st) => st.todos)
```

This tells the entity adapter to access the `todos` property of whatever object is passed in to the selector functions in order to get the data managed by the adapter.

When you call a selector, pass in your application's root state:

```js
const todos = globalTodosReducers.selectAll(store.getState());
```

In the context of React, react-redux's `useSelector` function will do this for you:

```js
const todos = useSelector(globalTodosReducers.selectAll);
```

Comment: Thanks Bro , I Solved my issue using 
 // const { loading } = useSelector((state) => state.todos);
  // const todos = globalTodosReducers.selectAll(store.getState());
and also by 
const { loading, todos } = useSelector((state) => ({
    loading: state.todos.loading,
    todos: globalTodosReducers.selectAll,
  }));